# SSR for transformer tap changer?

Tags: transformer, relay, solid-state-relay

I need to regulate and possibly adjust an AC output voltage during operation, owing to certain circumstances. Problem is that the unit is pretty much too remote and inaccessible to replace any relay stuck or otherwise failed and I'm not in full control how many cycles they need to go through but the upside is that price isn't an issue and low volume.

Search terms for transformer tap changers gives plenty of results, but they are almost all for in-tank MVA-sized transformers. I'm in the 100-1000 VA range.

COTS SSRs for 230 Vac are plentiful, but they were all SPST. If I put one of the on each tap (primary or secondary), that would mean that two selected at once would blow a fuse (and possibly the SSR) which is not acceptable. Is there a standard method to use SPST in a SPDT fashion where two inputs (or outputs) cannot be selected at the same time by design? Is there a search term I'm missing here?

My design goals are:

- No maintenance required (or possible really).
- Impossible to short a winding (and blow a fuse) due to MCU/PLC doing something bad.

There is some hold-up on the secondary side downstream so if a few cycles are missing during switchover, that's acceptable.

Is there a standard solution for this? I don't need you to design it for me, I'm more looking for a search term to move forward.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTj65o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Winny, how many taps do you need to control?

Comment: I built a prototype with three on the primary and four on the secondary. Plenty of permutations to choose between there. I can probably make due with fewer if that helps.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to get a feel for this question. What range of adjustment do you go for in terms of tap ratios and how much do the tap ratios mean in terms of voltage. Just trying to get a better picture (I may not offer an answer of course unless something springs to mind)

Comment: @Andyaka Oh! I try to regulate away about 10 % mains variation and enable 10 % output voltage adjustment on top of that. It ended up with several % allowed variation per step.

Comment: Just a thought - overall you have a variation of 20% which might be achieved by adding or subtracting a sinewave in series with the secondary via some solid state PWM inverter module thingy. +/-20% of 1000 VA is only +/-100 VA and it sounds feasible and you would have a lot of control (almost linear control). Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a demux controlled by the MCU, that way no matter what the MCU did, only one output could be selected at a time. Ideally, you'd also implement some dead time insertion in hardware, though you might trust the MCU to do that by blanking the output enable during switching.

This is for the [SN74LVC138A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc138a.pdf)

[image]